# Width and height classes of Tailwind not working when sending them as props

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to make a resizable box component. This was the code I came up with

```
export default function Box({ className="", width, height}: {className?: String, width: string, height: string}) {
   return (
      <div className={`w-${width} h-${height} ${className}`}></div>
   )
}
```

I used it in the main page.tsx like this

```
<Box 
    width="32" 
    height="32"/>
```

It did not work. I even tried to make the width and height more explicit by providing arbitrary values using `h-[${height}]` and `w-[${width}]` but it was just not working.

But, when I tried to do the same in `className` of the box component, it did work and the strange thing is that if I, for instance wrote

`<Box className="w-10 h-10">`

Then, if I again tried my original way, by using props, it worked (even after removing the className). Kind of like, it was somehow cached. Other values were still not working. Any fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names in definitions as you have said like:

  ```
  <Box className="w-[32px] h-[32px]">
  ```

  or

  ```
  <Box width="w-[32px]" height="h-[32px]">
  ```

  ```
  export default function Box({ className="", width, height}: {className?: String, width: string, height: string}) {
     return (
        <div className={`${width} ${height} ${className}`}></div>
     )
  }
  ```
- Using the `style` attribute like:

  ```
  <Box width="32" height="32"/>
  ```

  ```
  export default function Box({ className="", width, height}: {className?: String, width: string, height: string}) {
     return (
        <div className={className} style={{ height, width }}></div>
     )
  }
  ```